# Change Excel SQL Command with macros

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I need to create a Excel 2010 macro, which changes the SQL Command text of a Excel Connection. I'm working with a SQL Server, if it matters.

How could I do this? I've found several links online, but none of them have worked.

The most recent code I used:

```
Dim comText As String

comText = "select  top 10000 [activitypointer0.subject] as subject , [activitypointer0.activityid] as activityid , [activitypointer0.instancetypecodename] as instancetypecodename , [activitypointer0.scheduledend] as scheduledend , [activitypointer0.createdbyname] as createdbyname , [activitypointer0.activitytypecodename] as activitytypecodename , [a_9cdbdceab5ee4a8db875050d455757bd.name] as [a_9cdbdceab5ee4a8db875050d455757bd.name]"
comText = comText & " from  FilteredActivityPointer as [activitypointer0] left outer join FilteredAccount as [a_9cdbdceab5ee4a8db875050d455757bd] on ([activitypointer0.regardingobjectid]  =  [a_9cdbdceab5ee4a8db875050d455757bd.accountid])"
comText = comText & " where  ([activitypointer0.activitytypecode] = 4201 and ([activitypointer0.ownerid] in (N'{69CB3CDE-0998-E011-916A-00155D000607}' , N'{D8D40800-B798-E011-916A-00155D000607}' , N'{7ECB3CDE-0998-E011-916A-00155D000607}' , N'{70CB3CDE-0998-E011-916A-00155D000607}')) and [activitypointer0.statecode] = 1 and  [activitypointer0.scheduledendutc] >= '20111231 22:00:00'  and  [activitypointer0.scheduledendutc] < '20120131 22:00:00' )"
comText = comText & " order by  [activitypointer0.subject] asc , [activitypointer0.activityid] asc"

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("conCRM").ODBCConnection
    .commandText = comText
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("conCRM").Refresh
```

This is giving me an error about column names.

[image: Column name error]

Comment: What code do you currently have, what have you specifically tried, and in what manner didn't it work?

Comment: Your question is way to vague for us to help you. You need to provide more details

Comment: I edited my question and added the most recent code I used.

Comment: Does the query run correctly in SQL Server?  I'm not much with SQL, but "[a_9cdbdceab5ee4a8db875050d455757bd.name] as [a_9cdbdceab5ee4a8db875050d455757bd.name]" looks funny to me.

Comment: I changed it, but the problem was not solved. It's giving me errors about column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should be using column names like `[activitypointer0].[subject]` instead of `[activitypointer0.subject]` (and others like it) if the error you get is only "complaining" about column names.

Comment: You solved it, leoinfo! You made me very happy. Thank you very much!